# CSS y HTML: Botón en parte inferior de contenedor

Tags: html, css

Apenas estoy comenzando con CSS y tengo una duda a ver si me pueden orientar con esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer ese botón que se ve abajo "Get started". En realidad coloque un div para simular el botón por el momento y luego seguramente le colocaré un ... Mi HTML es este:

```
                    <div class="box-custom-plans-calc-total">
                        <div class="box-info-plans">
                            <div class="box-info-plans-header">
                                <h5 class="title2-plans"><?php the_field('item_resume_1'); ?></h5>
                                <h5 class="title2-plans">$<span id="calc-total"></span></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-info-plans">
                            <div class="box-info-plans-header">
                                <h5 class="title2-plans"><?php the_field('item_resume_2'); ?></h5>
                                <h5 class="title2-plans">- $<span id="calc-discount">0</span></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="separate-box-info-plans"> </div>
                        <div class="box-info-plans">
                            <div class="box-info-plans-header">
                                <h5 class="title2-plans"><?php the_field('item_resume_3'); ?></h5>
                                <h5 class="title2-plans">$<span id="calc-grand-total"></span><span>/month</span></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button-total text-center">
                            Get started
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Y el CSS para el div del botón lo coloque así:

```
.button-total {

    background-color: #63ACFC;

    color: #fff;

    margin-top: 20px;

    margin-left: -26px;

    margin-right: -26px;

    margin-bottom: -11px;

    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;

    padding: 35px;

}
```

El problema es que obviamente, cuando se reduce la pantalla todo se mueve y el div para el botón no se acopla.

Gracias de antemano...

Comment: Yo te recomendaría que en lugar de colocar margenes negativos, que en nada ayudan al diseño responsive, coloques el div "button-total" dentro y al final del contenedor "box-info-plans"

Comment: Necesito un poco más de contexto para estar seguro de la solución, intenta editar tu pregunta y agrega un poco más de código y también capturas de lo que pasa con tu página vs. lo que quisieras que pase